# Standard way to return JSON for view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, standards

I've got a view with a few simple fields and a jQuery grid.  The fields I populate via my Model so my first thought was to try and populate my grid via the same way.  The thing is that after banging my head against the problem for a bit I started to wonder if maybe I was trying to go against the grain to much.  It seems like the generally accepted practice (and more importantly how things are designed) that components on the view which use json for their data work best when they can make a separate call to get a JSONResult returned which they will then process.

Normally this wouldn't be a big deal but for various future proofing reasons (not my decision.. the fun of having an architect) we've got a separate WCF layer that our MVC layer calls.  So now I have to be worried about making too many granular calls.  This is what actually lead me to try the model based population approach.  What I'm wondering is how common this approach is or if everyone just has a bunch of controller methods for their UI components to call to get JSON?

Comment: The architecture as it is cannot be changed.  You have as much luck overriding an architect in an enterprise environment as you do getting the sun to come up early.  What I'm looking for is how to do things while taking into account the cost of remote calls to our WCF layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a standard generic model for JSON results like

```
 public class JSONOutputModel<T>{

       public int RequestId{ get; set; }

       public string Type { get{ return typeof(T).FullName; } }

       public T Model{ get; set; }

 }
```

Then I have standard generic send/receive JSON methods in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The most generic way you can return json from an action is to simply call the Json() method.

```
return Json(viewModel);
```

If you are specifically returning data for jqGrid, you could use your own ActionResult. Here is what we use. We also have an extension method to translate to this result from our service paging wrapper.

```
public class TableResult : ActionResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Write(ToJqGridJson());
    }

    public object ToJqGridJson()
    {
        return new {total = Total, page = Page, records = Records, rows = Rows};
    }

    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int Records { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public object[] Rows { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller:

```
return new TableResult() { ... };
```

or
    return queryResults.ToTableResult();

As far as future-proofing, don't even try! You're going to end up with a lot of big up front design and I guarantee it won't pay off. We learned the hard way and just recently started throwing out lots of our abstractions. There's no sense writing code if you don't know exactly how it's going to be used in the future. Besides, WCF can easily be replaced by an MVC app itself. MVC doesn't have to return just web sites. We have switched to using .net 4.0's javascript serializer + MVC + a client javascript deserializer to provide web services. You can share the authentication you already wrote for MVC, plus all your filters, etc and not have to worry about configuring the hideous mess of WCF. Look at where technology is moving towards: mobile and integrated! You aren't going to be doing WCF on your phone. Look at JSON, ATOM, RSS etc.

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2011/02/23/flatten-your-architecture-simplicity-as-a-core-value.aspx

Comment: I wasn't asking for a response to our architecture.  You've obviously never worked in an Enterprise if you think we can override an architect ;)

Comment: Was the remainder of my answer not relevant? (And I do work in enterprise. I've learned most "architects" are only architects in name.)

Comment: ps, does the action that just returns a ViewResult with the jqGrid need to make a WCF call? Can you cache things so you don't have to call the service so much? A common fallacy with these services is building a SELECT N+1 scenario (and it's not obvious until after the system becomes critical!) when you could really be caching the simple queries client-side (in your case, in the web app).